# Is there any other way to automatically rotate secrets in the keyvault other than function app?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I would like to rotate all the secrets in the given keyvault every 180 days. The keyvault and all the secrets are defined by Terraform. For AWS there is
aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation but I haven't found anything like that for Azure. The only way that I've found is creating function app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation but I would like to avoid solution with custom code that is outside of any source version control.

Are there any other options than function app?

Answer (score 1):

Secret rotation is not currently supported in Azure Key Vault. You can place Azure Functions source in source control, though. See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment. VSCode even has some great templates to get you started.